# Pass Linux variable in Oracle script

Tags: linux, bash, sql, oracle-database, oracle

How to pass Linux variable in Oracle code?

I need to pass it in below format and it should not ask for "enter a value for 1:"

Please advise.

```
mount='/u08/dbname/'
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" <<EOF 
set serveroutput on;
set feedback off;
set verify off;
set heading off;
DECLARE
line varchar(100);
BEGIN 
line := '&1';
if (5 > 0)then
dbms_output.put_line(line);
end if;
END;
/
$mount
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export mount='/u08/dbname/'
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" <<EOF 
set serveroutput on;
set feedback off;
set verify off;
set heading off;
DECLARE
line varchar(100);
BEGIN 
line := '$mount';
if (5 > 0) then
dbms_output.put_line(line);
end if;
END;
/
$mount
EOF
```

You can assign the output of a Unix/Linux command to a variable too:

```
export SPACE=$(df --output=avail -m /dev/sda8 | tail -1)
```

Comment: The mount point value is dynamically created in the linux code. We are not providing constant value here.
suppose I am calculating a space available on filesystem.
space=df -m dir
How should I provide that value?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Its working fine!
Thanks much Gerard!!

Comment: Perhaps you could accept the answer?